Yii2 azure hosting
I have created a web app on a Linux profile.
After that, I followed these steps:
cd path/to/your/yii2-app
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add azure <your-azure-git-url>
git push azure master

I can see that my code is pushed to Azure.
Under "Configuration", I went to "General settings" and added this command:
php yii serve --docroot=@/home/wwwroot/web --port=8000

Now, when I go to the domain, it shows the default page:

"Your web app is running and waiting for your content."

How can I fix this? I cannot see any errors in the logs, and the deployment is also successful.
Can somebody help me this what step is missed
cd path/to/your/yii2-app
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add azure <your-azure-git-url>
git push azure master

NOw i am expecting at least i can see the login page of my code

Make sure you have set the correct permission for assets and runtime directory. Give it a try to set 777 and see whether is works or not. But I'm not recommend to set 777. Otherwise you can set the ownership.
